# Twilio WebRTC Video freezing on Mobile Web

Tags: mobile, reactjs, webrtc, twilio

I've implemented the Twilio Video quickstart code in my project using ReactJS and after a few tweaks, it all seems to work fine on chrome and firefox from my computer, but when I try to use either the preview or make a call with another client from my mobile web browser, the video does not move.  It is stuck, but the video streams will work fine if I am moving the screen with my finger or if my finger is just on the screen, but will freeze on it's current frame the moment I stop moving the screen. I am not sure if this is an issue with the way Twilio attaches the video or if there is just something about mobile browsers that I don't understand when attaching video streams.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few things that could be going on here. Currently and also for the foreseeable future, Twilio Video will require the A6 system on chip, so older devices like an iPod Touch (5th gen) for example, would not supported.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/system-requirements

You might try to modify the bitrate indirectly through modifying the resolution. There is some sample code (in Swift) demonstrating this API:

https://github.com/twilio/video-sample-ios-capture-render/blob/master/VideoSampleCaptureRender/ViewController.swift#L205

Lastly, reporting of connection information through the conversation delegate does receive statistics:

https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/conversations/releases/0.22.0/docs/Protocols/TWCConversationDelegate.html#//api/name/conversation:didReceiveTrackStatistics:

however there is not an automatic way to adjust the resolution based on these statistics.

Hope this helps to point you in the right direction. Please let me know in the comments what you find out.

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified that I am trying this on an Android device (Samsung s6) and I am not using the iOS sdk. This is all web development using javascript (reactJS)

Comment: Ahh cool. Regardless, a lot of these same principles may apply. But if you send in your code sample with device specifics and any relevant log information, we can dig a little deeper on the support side. twilio.com/help/contact